# Play: should you always use Action.async?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm a little confused about how Play! works in its controller layer. Some documentation states that Play! is always asynchronous and non-blocking. So I'm confused by Action vs Action.async. Is Action blocking? If so, and docs say that you should always stay asynchronous and non-blocking, then should you always use Action.async in all your controllers? Why would you choose not too? I'm sure there's something that I'm not understanding here, and any of your expertise would be greatly appreciated in understanding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play is fully asynchronous and non-blocking.

Most actions tend to require being executed inline and so Play conveniently reflects this. However if you have an async operation within your action (calling WS for example) then you use Action.async to pass back the future result.

Answer (score 1):

`Action` is blocking and it takes a function from `Request=>Result`, so you can do any blocking stuff in it. `Action.async` is non-blocking and requires a function from `Request=>Future[Result]`  but here it is important to realize that only non-blocking stuff in it has matter, because if you block some where further it would be pointless. WS call mentioned by @Christopher Hunt is a good example because it gives you a Future[Response] that you can easily transform to `Future[Result]` what is expected by Action.async as a return type. But you are free to use `scala.Future API` for any stuff that might be async & non-blocking.

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaAsync

**Actions are asynchronous by default**

Play [actions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaActions) are asynchronous by default. For instance, in the controller code below, the `{ Ok(...) }` part of the code is not the method body of the controller. It is an anonymous function that is being passed to the `Action` object’s `apply` method, which creates an object of type `Action`. Internally, the anonymous function that you wrote will be called and its result will be enclosed in a `Future`.

```
def echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

**Note:** Both `Action.apply` and `Action.async` create `Action` objects that are handled internally in the same way. There is a single kind of `Action`, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one). The `.async` builder is just a facility to simplify creating actions based on APIs that return a `Future`, which makes it easier to write non-blocking code.